# TSQL Nested IF logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I am using to pull data to my page. Currently, you can select a "Location" on my report and show data for that location. I want to add a "Global" option so when that is selected, the query will return ALL data.

This is my current working SP when querying the data by location:

```
IF (@action = 'segment')

    BEGIN
        SELECT   B.[segmentName],
                 count(A.[segmentID]) AS total,
                 A.[meetingID],
                 C.[center]
        FROM     Focus_Meetings_Segments AS A
                 INNER JOIN
                 Focus_Segments AS B
                 ON A.[segmentID] = B.[id]
                 JOIN Focus_Meetings as C
                 ON C.[id] = A.[meetingID]
        WHERE C.[center] = @location
        GROUP BY B.[segmentName], A.[meetingID], C.[center]
        ORDER BY total DESC
        FOR      XML PATH ('segment'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
    END
ELSE
```

Her is how the query would be for ALL data:

```
IF (@action = 'segment')

    BEGIN
        SELECT   B.[segmentName],
                 count(A.[segmentID]) AS total
        FROM     Focus_Meetings_Segments AS A
                 INNER JOIN
                 Focus_Segments AS B
                 ON A.[segmentID] = B.[id]
        GROUP BY B.[segmentName], A.[segmentID]
        ORDER BY total DESC
        FOR      XML PATH ('segment'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
    END
ELSE
```

Is there a way do do this inline with case logic or possible to do a nested if statement like below?

```
IF (@action = 'segment')
    IF (@location = 'global')
```

Comment: Is it true that you don't want to join to `Focus_Meetings` in the `global` case, or is that an oversight?  Should the only different just be the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: When I do it globally, I dont need the focus meetings table as that is where it contains the actual location of the meeting which is then attached to the segments.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two different Statements.  Just change the Where clause so that it is conditional based on the value of @location

```
 Where C.[center] = coalesce(@location, C.[center])
```

and then just pass a null when you want them all.

NOTE:  If join to B can fail sometimes, make it an Outer join.

```
    SELECT B.[segmentName],
       count(A.[segmentID]) AS total,
        A.[meetingID],
         C.[center]
    FROM  Focus_Meetings_Segments AS A
       JOIN Focus_Segments B
          ON A.[segmentID] = B.[id]
       Left JOIN Focus_Meetings as C
          ON C.[id] = A.[meetingID]
             And C.[center] = coalesce(@location, C.[center])
    GROUP BY B.[segmentName], A.[meetingID], C.[center]
    ORDER BY total DESC
    FOR  XML PATH ('segment'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

Comment: Can this be changed to work with `@location = 'global'` instead of null ?

Comment: Also I don't think this will work correctly as the JOIN will break when there is no data for center (@location)

Comment: Then make the join an outer join

Comment: I changed it prior to your comment to test it but it still returns NULL when I don't pass anything to @location

Comment: I changed it to what you have above but now it returns ALL data regardless of what @location is

Comment: Without seeing your data I can only hazard a guess as to what is going on. The "guess" is that by "All the data" yopu are referring to data from tables other than `Focus_Meetings`.  The SQL query as I desfcribed it will NOT return ALl data from `Focus_Meetings`. It will return only those rows that match A.[meetingID], and (if you pass a value for (@location), that match the location.  What you are probably seeing is that it is returning all data from `Focus_Meetings_Segments` and/or `Focus_Segments B` This is the nature of an outer join.

Comment: You can try taking the `Left` off, (Make it an inner join again), but again, not seeing your data, I'm not sure exactly what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55332/discussion-between-sbb-and-charles-bretana).

Comment: I removed the left join but the output is still empty when running the query with no location passed.